# SWT Browser Plugin does not promt for proxy authentication

Tags: authentication, browser, swt, mozilla, prompt

I have successfully configured my SWT Browser application to use the proxy by setting VM arguments -Dnetwork.proxy_host and -Dnetwork.proxy_port to the according values.

However the proxy needs authentication, but the username / password prompt does not open. Futhermore when registering an authentication listener, the listener is never triggered.

The problems occured with a Linux Debian 64 Bit distribution. When compiling the same application for windows, all works fine, i.e. the password promt opens. The SWT Browser is configured to use MOZILLA, not WEBKIT. Unfortunatelly I cannot test with WEBKIT as I am limited to a given environment.

Temp solution: When starting the Linux Mozilla Browser, the prompt comes up. If entering there correct values and afterwards starting the SWT Browser application, then no authentication is needed at all and internet access is possible. But this is not a good solution.

When I register a location listener with "addLocationListener" to look whats going on with url calls, then I can see that the initial url (for example www.google.de) results to call a certain http site of the proxy server. And this http site is a redirect to a https site of the proxy. Then the https site results in calling the http redirect page again. This is then an endless loop.
I would guess that somewhere in the JAVA code of the SWT Browser class there is a routine that calls setUrl with those pages (what results in an 
endless loop) and skip to call any authentication listener for some reason.

Maybe someone has an idea whats going wrong in this authentication process?

Answer (score 1):

I have no solution but a hint: I'm not sure what you mean by "Linux Mozilla Browser" - I know Firefox and Xulrunner. But your workaround suggests that profile information is shared somehow and that shouldn't happen.

I tried to find some information how to define the profile (where the web browser keeps its cache, config, SSL certificates, plugins, ...) but to no avail.

This entry in the FAQ shows how to set the proxy host: [How do I set a proxy for the Browser to use?](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#browserproxy)

Try to find a way to add the user/password information into the request sent to the proxy server. If that fails, create a local proxy which connects to the real proxy as upstream and which can authenticate itself.

Looking at the bug database, there is no support for Browser profiles: [Flexible Mozilla profile support - new API request](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=178918)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I meant indeed the Firefox application with "Linux Mozilla Browser". I installed now on my notebook a local proxy (squid) with password authentication on my notebook, there all works fine, i.e. the prompt comes up. But difficult to say because the environment is a bit different (same java program, but probably different proxy configuration, architecture and linux distribution. I will continue to investigate this problem at work.

Comment: And yes, seems indeed to share some authentication data between the  applications. Not sure if this is a wanted behaviour or not.

Comment: This shouldn't happen; which version of SWT are you using?